# Can I simplify this Java Generics Hierarchy

Tags: java, generics

Sometimes in my code I'd like to refer to (what I think of as) the implicit type in a generics heirarchy (basically the type implied by the first ? in the following).

```
public class Foo<BAR extends Bar<?>> {
  public void t(BAR x) {
    List l = new ArrayList();
    Object baz = x.makeBaz(null);
    l.add(baz);
    x.setBazList(l);
  }
}

public interface Bar<BAZ extends Number> {
  public BAZ makeBaz(Object arg1);
  public List<BAZ> getBazList();
  public void setBazList(List<BAZ> baz);
}
```

For example in the above code would it be possible to replace the lines

```
    List l = new ArrayList();
    Object baz = x.makeBaz(null);
```

with something using generics?

I would prefer to avoid having to write:

```
public class Foo<BAZ extends Number, BAR extends Bar<BAZ>> {
  public void t(BAR x) {
    List<BAZ> l = new ArrayList<BAZ>();
    BAZ baz = x.makeBaz(null);
    l.add(baz);
  }
}
```

since it feels unnatural to force this on the declaration of any derived classes.

I know the above is a bit contrived, but it's a lot simpler than trying to show the actual code I'm looking at.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the main problem is that you need to somehow enforce that the type you get out of `x.makeBaz()` is the same as the type parameter of the list you give to `x.setBazList(l)`, and that if you just use `?` you lose that enforcement ability, so you need a generic type parameter. But in a sense the type parameter is only needed "locally" in those few lines and the rest of the class shouldn't need to know.

You could use the type parameter `BAZ` to parameterize just the method instead of the class:

```
public <BAZ extends Number> void t2(Bar<BAZ> x) {
  List<BAZ> l = new ArrayList<BAZ>();
  BAZ baz = x.makeBaz(null);
  l.add(baz);
  x.setBazList(l);
}
```

This serves to localize the region of code where we need this temporary type variable `BAZ`. Note that this method's signature is effectively `public void t2(Bar<?> x)`, i.e. the outside doesn't need to know about this `BAZ`.

Now of course this method now accepts all `Bar<anything>` instead of just `BAR`. If this is an issue, you could just "wrap" the above method. We don't have the same problem as before because all the `BAZ` stuff is already enclosed inside `t2()`, which takes a `Bar<anything>`, so we can safely pass a `BAR`:

```
public void t(BAR x) {
  t2(x);
}
```

I agree that this seems kind of roundabout. Maybe someone else will come up with a better way.

Comment: by the way this is called "capture helper": http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp04298.html#3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can at least bind to Number as BAZ extends Number

```
public class Foo<BAR extends Bar<?>> {
    public void t(BAR x) {    
        List<Number> l = new ArrayList<Number>();
        Number baz = x.makeBaz(null);
        l.add(baz);
        // l.add(Integer.valueOf(1)); compiles but with this here the next line throws ClassCastException
        x.setBazList(l);
    }
}

public interface Bar<BAZ extends Number> {
    public BAZ makeBaz(Object arg1);
    public List<BAZ> getBazList();
    public void setBazList(List<BAZ> baz);
}

public class BarConcreate implements Bar<BigDecimal>{
    long counter = 1;

    private List<BigDecimal> list = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
    public List<BigDecimal> getBazList() {
        return list;
    }


    public BigDecimal makeBaz(Object arg1) {
        return BigDecimal.valueOf(counter++);
    }

    public void setBazList(List<BigDecimal> baz) {
        list = baz;         
        for(BigDecimal d : baz){
            logger.debug("value:" + d.toString());
        }
    }

}


public void TestFooBar(){
    Foo<Bar<BigDecimal>> foo = new Foo<Bar<BigDecimal>>();
    Bar<BigDecimal> bar = new BarConcreate();
    foo.t(bar);
}
```

This java compiles and runs if the List is only filled with BigDecimal every thing works if the List has an integer in it we get a class cast exception on the line x.setBazList(l);

I find that very interesting.

Comment: that will not type-check, as x.setBazList() wants a List<BAZ> not a List<Number>

Comment: It compiles and runs, which I find a little strange but I did check before adding the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for this if you like it:

```
List<Number> l = new ArrayList<Number>();
Number baz = x.makeBaz(null);
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Also this makes sense:

```
public class Foo<BAR extends Bar<? extends Number>>
```

Comment: that will run into problems when you get to x.setBazList(l)